# Problematic frame: # C [egl_gallium.so+0x21e9ce] radeon_drm_winsys_create+0x5355e

Tags: java, opengl, ubuntu

When I try to start an specific app that use OpenGL libraries, I get the next message:

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

> > SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fbacbc719ce, pid=7743, tid=140441407649536
> >
> > JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_40-b43) (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
> >      Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.0-b56 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
> >      Problematic frame:
> >      C  [egl_gallium.so+0x21e9ce]  radeon_drm_winsys_create+0x5355e
> >
> > Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
> >
> > An error report file with more information is saved as:
> >      /home/pc/develop/hs_err_pid7743.log
> >
> > If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
> >        http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
> >      The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
> >      See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

This app was working well in ubuntu 13.04 (64 bits), but I have upgraded to 13.10 (64 bits).

I have tried everything to fix this problem: I have checked opengl and it is working without problems.  I have checked the last version for the graphic libs, etc. but I can not fix it.

Anybody has an idea how to fix it?

PD:
Some important information:

OS:
Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy (64bits)

Graphic Contoler:
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Pitcairn XT [Radeon HD 7870 GHz Edition]

OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 9.2.1

Comment: That is most likely an issue with your graphics driver. Also happens without Java: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=957531

Comment: yes, i have checked, but, do you know how can I try to figure out a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The bug seems to be rare (although reported in multiple projects) - maybe just a certain graphic setting or combination of settings is causing that. The offending function seems to be DRM related so maybe you can get it to work if you play with settings regarding video-playback?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it!

It was necesary to change drivers to "propietary" from "Software & Updates" -> Additional Drivers , check the option "Using Video Driver for AMD graphics accelerators from fglrx-updates(propietary)".

The new drivers will be downloaded and installed. 
Finally, restart the computer.